# MessageSource is not being injected by Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I'm having an issue using MessageSource and Spring. For some unknown (for me, at least) reason, my `messageSource` object is not being instantiated.

I have the following components:

`applicationContext.xml`

```
...
<import resource="messageSource-ctx.xml" />
...
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />
...
```

`messageSource.xml`

```
<beans ...>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>backendErrorCodesMapping</value>
                <value>restErrorCodesMapping</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

`MessageSourceHelper.java`

```
package com.foo.bar.util;

@Component
public class MessageSourceHelper {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    ...
}
```

`GenericRestExceptionMapper.java`

```
package com.foo.bar.rest.exception

@Component
public abstract class GenericRestExceptionMapper{

    @Resource
    private MessageSourceHelper msh;

    ....
}
```

`InvalidRequestExceptionMapper.java`

```
package com.foo.bar.rest.exception

@Provider
public class InvalidRequestExceptionMapper extends GenericRestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<InvalidRequestException> {

...

}
```

Once an `InvalidRequestException` occurs, it will be "cought" by the `InvalidRequestExceptionMapper`, that uses the inherited `msh` (MessageSourceHelper). The issue is that this object is null, i.e., it is not being injected by Spring.

What should be the problem? I appreciate all the help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `@Provider`? Are you sure that `InvalidRequestExceptionMapper` is managed by Spring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `InvalidRequestExceptionMapper` should have `@Component` and `private MessageSourceHelper msh;` should have `@Autowired`

Comment: Thanks Arun! That worked pretty well!
The issue was the missing `@Component`annotation in the `InvalidRequestExceptionMapper`